# How to set parameter type taken from variable

Tags: c#, .net

For example this is what i need:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

public class Prog
{
    public static Type myType = typeof(IntPtr);

    public static void Main() {
        var handle = new IntPtr(12345);
        SetForegroundWindow(handle);
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(myType hWnd);
}
```

How to write it down correctly? Visual studio underlines **myType** in method import.

Comment: You can't do this in C#. Parameter types have to be known at compile time for method signatures. However, there's lots of different approaches that will normally achieve what you want to (e.g. generics, reflection) - so please explain what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: (from your code it looks like you should just set the parameter to `IntPtr` but I'm assuming your real use is more complicated? I can't think why you would ever need this when p/invoking though - the native method you are calling will always have a fixed signature)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, Type is an IntPtr, so I would think:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

is enough to PInvoke the SetForegroundWindow method. This is a static API and the compiler doesnt need reflection to bind to it, it just wants to know the contract to that API, which in this case just takes a single `IntPtr` to the window handle.

When you declare

```
public static Type myType = typeof(IntPtr);
```

you are creating a variable (statically) named `myType` which holds the type information for the type `IntPtr`. That information cant really be used in a method signature, its more useful in runtime reflection scenarios. In order to use an `IntPtr` in your method signature you need to use the actual type in the parameter declaration.